# how to use accordian menu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

hi to all
i am using wordpress for my site i wanna add accordian menu as a middle content of the index page how it possible plz help.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for a plugin or widget.

If you can find a widget, search for how to make a extra widgetized area.  Great tutorials and plugins are all over the web.

If you want further flexibility and you're familiar with code, search for jquery or javascript plugins.  They'll give you the code and docs for implementation, and you can put it in your theme files, probably one of your page templates.